# Top N results grouped Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query that allows me to only get the specific data I want and nothing more.

We will use TV's as an example. I have three brands of TVs and I want to see the top ten selling models of each brand. I only want to return 30 rows. One solution is unions, but that can get messy fast. Ideally there would be a WHERE ROWNUM grouping by situation.

```
SELECT 
    A.Brand
,   A.Model
,   A.Sales
FROM 
(   SELECT
        TV.Brand
    ,   TV.Model 
    ,   SUM(TV.SALES) AS SALES
    FROM TV_TABLE as TV
    ORDER BY 
        TV.Brand
    ,   SALES DESC
)   A
WHERE ROWNUM <10
```

In my code above I will get the top 10 total results from the inner query, but not 10 from each Grouping.

What I want to see is something like this:

> Brand: Model:  Sales 
>   Sony:   x10:    20
>   Sony:   X20:    18
>   Sony:   X30:    10
>   VISIO:  A40:    40
>   VISIO:  A20:    10

This is an oversimplified example, in practice I'll need to have 20-50 gropings and would like to avoid downloading all of the data and using a Pivot feature.

Comment: Please only use tags from the DB you are using.

Comment: I use both Oracle and MYSQL and the question can be applied for either.

Comment: In that case please explain if you need a query that can run on both or you just want a script that runs on either. Each database has features that are not available in the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 select Brand, Model, SALES
 from(
    select Brand, Model, SALES,row_number()over(partition by Brand order by SALES desc) rn
    from (
        SELECT TV.Brand, TV.Model,SUM(TV.SALES) AS SALES,
        FROM TV_TABLE as TV
        group BY TV.Brand,TV.Model
    )a
)b
where rn <= 10
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I applied it to my query and worked, and rather quickly too. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thnkas to you  it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TV.Brand, TV.Model, SUM(TV.SALES) AS SALES
FROM TV_TABLE TV
group by TV.Brand, TV.Model
order by SUM(TV.SALES) desc, TV.Brand
limit 30
```

Comment: your code is bring 30 rows of the best sale. but if all the 30 will be in one brand he want only 10 from this brand. look in my code.